# No messages received from 'com-***-topic/subscriptions/com-***-subscription'. Pending receive request timed out

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitor

How to hide No messages received from 'com-***-topic/subscriptions/com-***-subscription'. Pending receive request timed out TRACE from application insight as this message mostly consuming some amount daily quota.

I
have tried some sampling concept on applicationinsight.json and able to restrict for actuator but not able to find any solution for service bus related error.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-sampling-overrides

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/98758

Answer (score 0):

To filter out Service Bus related errors from Application Insights, you can create a custom **TelemetryProcessor** that looks for **ExceptionTelemetry** objects with a specific message or exception type related to Service Bus and excludes them from Application Insights.

As per the links and requirement provided, I tried to build a code try to implement in your own environment.

```
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.*;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryConfiguration;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetry.*;

public class ServiceBusExample {
    
    private static final String SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING = "<your-service-bus-connection-string>";
    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "com-example-topic";
    private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_NAME = "com-example-subscription";
    private static final String INSTRUMENTATION_KEY = "<your-instrumentation-key>";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        // Initialize the Service Bus client
        ServiceBusClientBuilder builder = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING);
        ServiceBusClient client = builder.buildClient();
        
        // Initialize the Application Insights telemetry client
        TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.getActive();
        configuration.setInstrumentationKey(INSTRUMENTATION_KEY);
        TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
        
        // Create a receiver for the subscription
        ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient receiver = client.createReceiverAsync(
            new ServiceBusReceiverOptions().setSubQueue(SubQueue.RECEIVE_AND_DELETE),
            new ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClientBuilder()
                .topicName(TOPIC_NAME)
                .subscriptionName(SUBSCRIPTION_NAME)
                .buildAsyncClient()
        );
        
        // Receive messages from the subscription
        receiver.receiveMessages(10).subscribe(
            message -> {
                // Process the received message
                telemetryClient.trackEvent(new EventTelemetry("MessageReceived"));
                System.out.printf("Received message: %s\n", message.getBody().toString());
            },
            error -> {
                // Handle any errors that occur during message processing
                telemetryClient.trackException(new ExceptionTelemetry(error));
                System.out.printf("Error occurred: %s\n", error.toString());
            },
            () -> {
                // Clean up any resources after all messages have been received
                telemetryClient.trackTrace(new TraceTelemetry("MessageReceiverCompleted"));
                System.out.println("Completed receiving messages.");
            }
        );
        
        // Wait for messages to be received
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        // Close the receiver and the Service Bus client
        receiver.close();
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Created Service Bus instance and created a receiver for the specified subscription. We then use the **receiveMessages** method to receive up to 10 messages from the subscription.
[image]
For each message that we receive, we track an event in Application Insights using the `TelemetryClient` class and print the message body to the console.

There is also another option is to use the sampling feature in Azure Application Insights to filter out the specific messages by configure the sampling rate to exclude the messages that match a specific pattern or criteria, such as the message text "No messages received from 'com--topic/subscriptions/com--subscription'. Pending receive request timed out TRACE" add a custom sampling rule in the ApplicationInsights.xml check below.

```
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
  <InstrumentationKey>your-instrumentation-key</InstrumentationKey>
  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <Add Type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebOperationIdTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add Type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebOperationNameTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add Type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebSessionTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add Type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebUserTelemetryInitializer"/>
  </TelemetryInitializers>
  <SamplingTelemetryProcessor>
    <Percentage>50</Percentage>
    <ExcludedTypes>Request</ExcludedTypes>
    <IncludedTypes>Trace</IncludedTypes>
    <ApplyToDiagnosticSource>true</ApplyToDiagnosticSource>
    <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
    <ExcludedTypeTargets>
      <ExcludedTypeTarget>java.util.logging.LogRecord</ExcludedTypeTarget>
    </ExcludedTypeTargets>
    <ExcludedTypes>
      <ExcludedType>Dependency</ExcludedType>
    </ExcludedTypes>
    <ExcludedTypeExceptions>
      <ExcludedTypeException>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</ExcludedTypeException>
    </ExcludedTypeExceptions>
    <ExcludedTypes>
      <ExcludedType>Trace</ExcludedType>
      <ExcludedTypeFilter>
        <Field>Message</Field>
        <Regex>.*No messages received from 'com--topic/subscriptions/com--subscription'. Pending receive request timed out TRACE.*</Regex>
      </ExcludedTypeFilter>
    </ExcludedTypes>
  </SamplingTelemetryProcessor>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

The expected output will be to receive and process messages from the Service Bus topic and subscription.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Suresh Chikkam. Can we achieve the same sampling using applicationinsights.json instead of above XML file? Because i am also using sampling to restrict healthcheck url in my applicationinsights.json file